# Javascript....driving me crazy....doesn't make sense

Tags: javascript

Ok...so I have this:

```
function checkFields()
{
    var isEmpty = true;
    var fname = trim(document.getElementById("fname").value);
    var lname = trim(document.getElementById("lname").value);
    var ruid = trim(document.getElementById("ruid").value);

    if(fname != "" && lname != "" && ruid != "")
    {
        isEmpty = false;
        radioStatus(isEmpty);
    }
 }
```

and if I fill out all 3 text fields, it makes "isEmpty" false like it should (and when I first load the page, it fails and the "isEmpty" stays true like stated .... but if I fill out all 3, and then erase one or two...then the fname = "" and lname = "" and ruid = ""....but it will fail this test and not make "isEmpty" true like it should..... even in debugging mode I am seeing that the variables are "" but its failing..

shouldn't this be that if any of these variables are NOT "" (thus have values in them) then it will fail since I used AND... right???? arg!!! help please ..

Comment: Because you used AND they must all be non-empty for false to be set. Change to OR if just any one of them needs to be non-empty. Like somebody else said, show the code that extracts the values because there's chance for error there too.

Comment: Where is the code that shows you getting the values from the text fields? Make sure you post all relevant code so we can get you the best answer possible. :)

Comment: Need more information. Where are they being set? When are these functions being ran?

Comment: I don’t see any expression setting `isEmpty = true`. So where should this happen in your opinion?

Comment: The title isn't clear, there are dozens of ... in the question. It's barely understandable.

Comment: You need to clearly describe what should cause the `if` to fail. At least one of the strings is empty? All strings are empty? I assume you want to ensure that all have values, which is what you're doing, which means the trouble is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Amongst the many confusing statements in the question is _'but if I fill out all 3, and then erase one or two...then the fname = "" and lname = "" and ruid = ""'_ - this contradicts itself: if you fill in all three and then erase only one or two then how can they all be blank again? Please show more of your code and then explain simply what you expect it to do.

Comment: Why have you changed from `&&` to `||` in your updated code? What is the actual code that is giving you trouble? And what is the desired condition? All empty or at least one empty?

Comment: Should the `radioStatus(isEmpty)` call be after the `if` statement (so that it gets called for both true and false cases)?

Comment: Is this a bit like what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/q9BzE/

Comment: thanks nnnnn....that should happen either way..i need to fix that

Comment: HOLY CRAP ...thank you nnnnnn....that is what was wrong....I needed the radiostatus to be outside the if statement.....so that it was called whether the if statement passed or not....    so it works now!! thanks....          I can't believe I missed that.....thanks SOOOOO MUCH!!!!!!!!

Comment: @nnnnnn: Looks like you've made someone happy. Please post your answer so this can be closed properly. I rolled back the SOLVED!!! message in the title.

Comment: Carine, please don't update your questions to show the solution, because that renders all the existing answers obsolete or nonsensical. Instead, please accept the answer that most helped you, or if none were right you should post your own answer and accept that. In this case it seems that what I said in my comment above was what you needed, so as @amnotiam suggested I've posted that as an answer. (I've changed your question back for you.)

Answer (score 2):

Should the `radioStatus(isEmpty)` call be after the if statement (so that it gets called for both the true *and* false cases)?

Note: you could simplify your function as follows:

```
function checkFields()
{
    var fname = trim(document.getElementById("fname").value);
    var lname = trim(document.getElementById("lname").value);
    var ruid = trim(document.getElementById("ruid").value);

    radioStatus(fname == "" || lname == "" || ruid == "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in javascript, you don't have to assign a value to a variable when you declare it, so you may want to make sure that the variables are not null or undefined also.

Alternatively, you could try something like:

```
if(!!fname && !!lname && !!ruid)
{   isEmpty = false;
    radioStatus(isEmpty);
}
```

This will execute the block if all variables have "truth-y" values. Empty strings, null, and undefined are all "false-y" in javascript, so the above should work fine for you.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear....i have edited it above

Answer (score 0):

`shouldn't this be that if any of these variables are NOT "" (thus have values in them) then it will fail since I used AND... right????`

The question is a bit hard to understand - since you're missing a lot of context - but this last statement of yours: **`if ANY of these variables are NOT ""`** is not true. If you want that, you'd need to use OR (`||`) not AND (`&&`).

What you have now reads: `if ALL of these variables are NOT ""`

Comment: see the thing is that all 3 have to be filled before this variable will be false..that is why I made it AND...i will edit to add the other code

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Steve on this, you're assuming a lot of context. It depends when the javascript is run. Are you running the test on submission of the form, on loading the page, or at some other point? If you want to do it on submission you might want to try something like:

```
$('#my-button').bind({
  //your check goes here
});
```

Comment: jQuery I assume? How did that find its way in?

Comment: is that not kosher around here? Sorry, still new to the community. Do we keep to the tags the original poster selected?

Comment: Yeah, try to keep it focused on the API that the OP is using. There tends to be quite a few *"hey, just use jQuery"* answers to JavaScript questions. Not saying that's what you intended, but it gets out of hand sometimes.

Comment: ...but welcome to StackOverflow. ;-)

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the tip. Will do.